# One word for self-clicked photographs

Tags: single-word-requests

Recently I came across this word which means "one's *self-clicked* photograph". I, however, do not remember where I read it or what that word was. The article in which I saw the word was regarding social networking websites where people place their own 'self clicked' photographs. Does anybody know that word?

I am not sure if that word is from urban lingo.

Comment: I have heard `self-portraits`

Comment: What do you mean by "self-clicked"? Does that mean the person clicks the "Like" button? Clicks on the pictures to emulate higher traffic? Or do you mean the person has simply uploaded a self-portrait, as @camelbrush suggested?

Comment: The word is 'selfie' as answered by @Si Taylor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Selfies](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/selfie): Pictures taken of oneself while holding the camera at arms length.

Answer (score 4):

Photographic [self-portraits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-portrait#Photo-portraits):

> Two methods of obtaining photographic self-portraits are widespread. One is photographing a reflection in the mirror, and the other photographing one's self with the camera in an outstretched hand. Eleazar Langman photographed his reflection on the surface of a nickel-plated teapot.

Colloquially, I've seen them referred to as *self-pics*. Twitter, for example, has a [#selfpic hashtag](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23selfpic&src=hash) where people can upload pictures of themselves, *which are often **NSFW***.